# Does Debezium DB2 connector support IBMi?

Tags: db2, cdc, debezium

I am working on capturing data changes in a DB2 database running on an iSeries with IBM i operating system. The documentation notes the connector works with "Db2/Linux 11.5.0.0, but our expectation is that the model would work for Windows, AIX and zOS as well."  There is no mention of IBM i. Have there been any successful uses with IBM i DB2 or would you expect it to work as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with the IBM Data Replication product.

IBM Data Replication (https://www.ibm.com/analytics/data-replication) can source from a variety of relational databases hosted on different operating systems, one of them being DB2 database running on iSeries with IBM i OS.

We have a number of clients who are leveraging this capability to produce data with high throughput to target databases as well as streaming platforms such as Apache Kafka.

Feel free to reach out to me and we can discuss how IBM Data Replication can solve your business use case.

Thanks,

Sunny

Comment: Thank you Sunny, this is quite helpful. I was not aware of IBM Data Replication capabilities.

Comment: Sunny, do you know if Postgres can be a target database? Our DB2 on IBM i will be the source.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dan,

Yes, IBM Data Replication can source from DB2 on IBM i and apply data to Postgres database. 

CDC Replication engine for FlexRep can apply data to EnterpriseDb, and supports the following version: 
- Postgres Plus Advanced Server 9.1 (9.1.2.2)
- EDB Postgres Advanced Server 9.6 (9.4.1212.0)
- EnterpriseDB JDBC Driver 42.2

Here's the page with more information: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdcflexrep.doc/concepts/supportedflexrepjdbcdrivers.html

Comment: Feel free to reach out the IBM Data Replication team at https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/topic/0TO500000001k76GAA/data-replication?language=en_US&productId=01t500000051ZdKAAU with any questions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Debezium connector for Db2 requires a license to IBM Data Replication to run the capture program.   The capture that Debezium uses does not have an IBM i support.

Whereas IBM Data Replication itself can directly source from all Db2 varieties including IBM i, as well as many other databases such as SQL Server, Oracle, Informix, Sybase, MySQL and PostgreSQL along with mainframe IMS and VSAM.